# dynamically changing table content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a table which generates dynamically,

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${usermap}">

<tr>
<td>${user.getUserName()}</td>
<td>${user.getIsActive()}</td>
<td id="status_${user.getUserName()}">${user.getBadLoginAttempts()}</td>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${user.getBadLoginAttempts()=='Active'}">
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary unlockBtn"  onClick="LockAccount('${user.getUserName()}','${user.getBadLoginAttempts()}')" >Lock</a></td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary unlockBtn" onClick="LockAccount('${user.getUserName()}','${user.getBadLoginAttempts()}')">UnLock</a></td>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</tr>
/c:forEach>
```

table is generating fine , by clicking link "Lock" 3rd column value should change Locked and link has to change "Unlock" and vice verse   so in javascript I am calling controller in Post method, The problem I am facing is, control goes to controller and make db change and write text to `PrintWriter` obj now I want to put it in respective table cell. How to do it please help me.

my Javascript is,

```
<script>

function LockAccount(userName,status){
alert(userName);
/* alert(status); */
   $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/UserLockController',{'userName':userName,'status':status},
function(data)
{
  document.getElementById("status_"+userName).value=html(data);
}); 
</script>
```

The controller post function is like this,

```
protected final void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {


    String inputParam = request.getParameter("userName");
    System.out.println(inputParam);
    String status=request.getParameter("status");
    System.out.println(status);
    System.out.println();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    ServiceManager.getHelperService(
            TeacherManagementHelper.class, request, response).lockUser(inputParam);
    out.println("Locked");


}
```

So finaly I want to give the effect like this

[Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/6Xm36/)

Comment: The fiddl works. I don't understand what problem you are having, but it doesn't seem to be related to javascript.

Comment: The fiddl is in jquery but I want change content from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
document.getElementById("status_"+userName).value=html(data);
```

with

```
document.getElementById("status_"+userName).innerHTML(data);
```